# Insert into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert invoice numbers from one database to another. The new database, invoiceNo is the primary key.  There are duplicate invoice numbers from the original database. I found the duplicates using

```
SELECT  SERIAL_NO,
COUNT(*) as cnt    
FROM HISTORY_INCIDENTS
group by SERIAL_NO having COUNT(*) > 1
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

I would like to place a -1 at the end of the second invoice so they will be unique.  Not sure how to do this is SQL

Comment: is `SERIAL_NO`  a text field (char, varchar, ...) ?

Comment: Do you only ever have at most **1 duplicate**?

Comment: Serial_no is an int.  Yes, there are at most 1 duplicate

Comment: if `serial_no` is an int, are you trying to subtract 1 from it?  If not, what field are you putting the value in that is a varchar field? (ints cant concatinate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CTE like this...

```
;
WITH    cteDups
          AS ( SELECT   SERIAL_NO ,
                        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              ( PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO ORDER BY SERIAL_NO )
               FROM     HISTORY_INCIDENTS
             )
    SELECT  CASE RN
              WHEN 2 THEN SERIAL_NO + '-1'
              ELSE SERIAL_NO
            END AS SERIAL_NO
    FROM    cteDups
```

see the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6863b/6).  This will create a row number of **2** when there's a duplicate, you can then use a `CASE` to check for any **2**'s, and assign the **-1** to that record.

**EDIT**: based on comment

```
DECLARE @HISTORY_INCIDENTS TABLE ( SERIAL_NO INT );
DECLARE @NewHISTORY_INCIDENTS TABLE ( SERIAL_NO VARCHAR(10) );

INSERT  INTO @HISTORY_INCIDENTS
        ( SERIAL_NO )
VALUES  ( 1 );
INSERT  INTO @HISTORY_INCIDENTS
        ( SERIAL_NO )
VALUES  ( 2 );
INSERT  INTO @HISTORY_INCIDENTS
        ( SERIAL_NO )
VALUES  ( 2 );
INSERT  INTO @HISTORY_INCIDENTS
        ( SERIAL_NO )
VALUES  ( 2 );

;
WITH    cteDups
          AS ( SELECT   SERIAL_NO ,
                        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO 
                                                           ORDER BY SERIAL_NO )
               FROM     @HISTORY_INCIDENTS
             )
    INSERT  INTO @NewHISTORY_INCIDENTS
            ( SERIAL_NO
            )
            SELECT  CASE RN
                      WHEN 2 THEN CAST(SERIAL_NO AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-1'
                      ELSE CAST(SERIAL_NO AS VARCHAR(10))
                    END AS SERIAL_NO
            FROM    cteDups

SELECT   SERIAL_NO
FROM    @NewHISTORY_INCIDENTS
```

Comment: @paqogomez This will select all records from the source DB, and append the **-1** to the duplicate records.

Comment: @paqogomez, from this: *I'm trying to insert invoice numbers from one database to another*, I took it that a query is required to take the data from one db to another by using a query?

Comment: @user3385991 this is your answer, please remember to mark it as such and upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

I used the ROW_NUMBER() function to calculate the number of times a serial number occurred in a inner derived table. In the main query, I make decisions on how to craft the new serial number based on the number of occurrences I found.

PS: done without an SQL editor.

```
SELECT
     SERIAL_NO
    ,SERIAL_NO + CASE WHEN [SERIAL_NO_Occurrence] > 1 THEN '-' + CAST([SERIAL_NO_Occurrence]-1 AS VARCHAR) ELSE '' END AS [SERIAL_NO_New]
FROM (

    -- inner derived table to select number of occurrences of each serial number
    SELECT      SERIAL_NO
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO
                    ORDER BY SERIAL_NO -- you should also have a PK field here to have deterministic results I think
                 ) AS [SERIAL_NO_Occurrence]
    FROM        HISTORY_INCIDENTS
) AS T1;
```